# Apache Synapse Property Configuration with variables

Tags: wso2

I am trying to add variables to a property in a synapse configuration file. The line looks like this(works fine):

`<property name="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('username:password'))" scope="transport"/>`

I am, however, trying to pass the username and password as parameters, which I've attempted to do with the following (and similar variations with the apostrophe being in different locations) but nothing is working:

`<property name="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode($url:username':'$url:password))" scope="transport"/>`

Any ideas or suggestions as to what is wrong?

Comment: figured it out:

`base64Encode(concat($url:username,':',$url:password)))`

Comment: Carl can you post that as an answer :).

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out: base64Encode(concat($url:username,':',$url:password)))